# Two columns different number of items same total height

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I am looking for some way to display this type of grid in html and css.

[image]

I want to stretch out the smaller column to match the taller one.  Is this possible?  I have tried a solution with some javascript, but am not really happy with the solution.  There are some complexities in that the column with the most rows may not be the tallest.  Also the boxes may be different heights if they have different amounts of content.

I am open minded about the markup to be used here, currently I am using two lists side by side, but a table or anything else is fine.  However, just using rowspan doesn't seem like it will work as this will just give one box that is much bigger than the others. This seems like it may be a common problem is there a good solution out there?

Comment: forgot to include this fiddle which is what I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/GgEUV/

Comment: Looks a lot like a masonry layout. Have you tried it? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: thanks for the answers, I'm marking the nested tables as the answer because it is very easy to understand and I can't really tell what is the best javascript solution.  The  Nirazul and yent answers don't cut off any text, whereas the hunter answer does but is nicely written so is helpful nonetheless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this can work

```
<table border="1" >
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0">
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're stuck with JS here. My approach would be to use percent-height on the elements in the lists.

- Determine the number of elements in each list.
- Divide 100 by that value (okay, tricky if 3, 6 ..., etc)
- Give each element its height in %
- Don't forget to set height on parent elements, or % wont work

Answer (score 1):

Took me awhile but here is the Fiddle and the JS-Code:

My solution will take into account the relational size of the elements and stretches them proportionally. For example: A div that took up 50% of the space will still be taking up 50% after stretchin the ul.

(There will be problems however when adding padding and border. If there's a solution to this, I would be interested, too!)

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var $allUl = $('ul');
    setNewPercentages($allUl);

    function getTallestUl($uls) {
        var max = 0;
        var $ulTallest;

        $uls.each(function(i,e) {
            console.log( $(this).height() > max);
            if( $(this).height() > max) {
                $ulTallest = $(this);
                max = $(this).height();
            }
        });

        return $ulTallest;
    };

    function adjustPercentages($ul) {
        $ul.find('li').each( function(i,e) {
            var $this = $(this)
            ,   ulHeight = $ul.height()
            ,   liHeight = $this.height()
            ,   percentage = (liHeight / ulHeight * 100);

            $this.css('height', percentage + '%');
        });
    };

    function setNewPercentages($uls) {
        var $tallest = getTallestUl($allUl).addClass('tallest');
        var heightTallest = $tallest.height();

        $uls.not('.tallest').each(function(i,e) {
            adjustPercentages($(this));
            $(this).css('height', heightTallest);
        });
    };
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgEUV/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/sG39d/

Things get a little tricky when you add in top/bottom margins and padding on the `li`

```
$(function() {
    var $tallest = null;
    var $ul = $("ul");

    $("ul").each(function() {
        if ($tallest == null || $(this).height() > $tallest.height()) {
            $tallest = $(this);
        }
    });
    var height = $tallest.height();
    $ul.not($tallest).each(function() {
        var update = height / $(this).find("li").length;
        $(this).find("li").css("height", update);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your fiddle :

```
var heights=[], cnt=0, cols=[];

$('ul').each(function () {
    cols.push(this);
    var h = 0;
    $(this).find('li').each(function() {
        h += $(this).innerHeight();
    });
    heights.push(h);
    cnt++;
});

var max = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

for(var i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
    var delta = Math.floor((max - heights[i]) / $(cols[i]).find('li').length);
    $(cols[i]).find('li').each(function() {
        $(this).css('height', $(this).innerHeight() + delta);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it's not easy to archieve...
try this :  [faux columns](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Item1</div>
      <div>Item2</div>
      <div>Item3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Item1</div>
      <div>Item2</div>
      <div>Item3</div>
      <div>Item4</div>
      <div>Item5</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Both columns will be the same height this way. The items in the shorter column won't stretch to fill the void though. I think you'll have to do that yourself with Javascript.